# Hi guys, How can I empty a field into the database if I fill in a different field

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework

The case is this, in have two types of discount in my application, these are discount by amount and discount by percentage and vice versa.

Here is my code:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        
        $input = $request->all();
        $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'client_id' => 'required|integer',
            'date' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d',
            'status' => 'required|integer',
            'currency' => 'required|string',
            'payment_type' => 'required|integer',
            'description' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'note'             => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'discount_percent' => 'nullable|numeric|',//exists:earnings,id
            'discount_amount'  => 'nullable|numeric'
        ]);

        // $length = 7;
        // $unique = '#'.str_pad($id,$length,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
   
        if($validator->fails()){
            return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors());       
        }

        $order = Order::find($id);
 
        $order->client_id=  $input['client_id'];
        $order->date= $input['date'];
        $order->status= $input['status'];
        $order->currency= $input['currency'];
        $order->payment_type= $input['payment_type'];
        $order->description= $input['description'];
       

        $order->save();    
        
        
        
        for($i=0; $i<count($input['product_id']);$i++)
        {
            if ($input ['discount_amount'] > 0) {
                $input ['discount_percent'] = 0;
            }
    
            if ($input ['discount_percent'] > 0) {
                $input ['discount_amount'] = 0;
            }
      

            $ordProduct = OrderProduct::where('order_id', $id)->where('product_id','=',$input['product_id'][$i])
            ->update(
            ['quantity' => $input['quantity'][$i],
             'note'=> $input['note'],
            'discount_percent'=> $input['discount_amount'] ? $input ['discount_amount'] : 0,
            'discount_amount'=>$input['discount_percent'] ? $input ['discount_percent'] : 0,
            'percent_id' => $input['percent_id']
            
            
               
        ]);

       

        }


        return $this->sendResponse($order, 'Order updated successfully.'); 
    }
```

The error I'm getting is that when I save a field the value I assign is not saved and is left at 0.

It should be 0 if a change it but i don't know why is not working.

Comment: `'discount_percent'=> $input['discount_amount']` Do you have that backwards? You're assigning the value of `discount_amount` to the `discount_percent` field... Also, you can just do `'discount_percent' => $request->input('discount_percent', 0)`. Lastly, are `discount_percent` and `discount_amount` set in your `OrderProduct` model's `$fillable` (or excluded from `$guarded`)?

Comment: Yes they are backwards,, and yes they are in my orderProduct Model

Comment: when you save what field the value isn't assigned?

Comment: I worry when I see things like `client_id` being set blindly from input. It means the user can set any value they like.

Comment: You don't need to test the values on every iteration of the product id?